# how to exclude a jquery event for a popover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing an issue where a generic javascript in my appliaction is causing my popover to hide. Below is the generic code.

```
    $(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.popover', function(event) {
    if (event.type == 'mouseenter') {
        //Code abc
    } else if (event.type == 'mouseleave') {
        //Code Def
        $("div.popover").remove();
   }
```

Can anyone please tell me how to exclude this javascript for my popover?

Comment: would modifying the selector help? something like `.popover:not(.special)`

Comment: The `.off()` method removes event handlers that were attached with `.on()`.

Comment: Console log the event.  IIRC, there should be an originalEvent or the like on it which should contain the element which the event originated from before it bubbled up to the popover.  You should be able to check to see if that element is the popover.  If it is not, ignore the event.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I tried :not selector and it worked. thank you so much!